Deepsetai: Haystack Meta data filtering on arrays
When using a Document Retriever with Haystack, you can filter the meta data.
A very important operator is the "in" operator, which allows you to check if one of the values specified in your array ["value a", "value b"] is in the meta data field.
Unfortunately for this approach the meta data field has to be a string or a number (I did not test Booleans).
Example document for this case:
{"content": "some content", "meta":{"field": "value b"}}

If you save a list in the meta field, than you can not use any operator on it.
So if your document looks like this:
{"content": "some content", "meta":{"field": ["value a", "value b"]}}
I can not filter for documents containing "value a" (It does not matter if they have any other value in the provided list).
Is there any known solution for this issue?
I could only this issue in the Haystack Repo.

Following the approach provided here. I have derived a custom PgvectorDocumentStore class and created a modified version of the filters.py by adding the following to the end.
It is not the best solution, but perhaps it will help somebody else.
def _contains(field: str, value: Any) -> Tuple[str, List]:
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        msg = f"'{field}' value must be a string when using 'contains' comparator."
        raise FilterError(msg)

    if field.startswith("meta->>'"):
        field = field.replace("->>'", "->'")
    elif field.startswith("meta.") and "->" not in field:
        field_name = field.split('.', 1)[-1]
        field = f"meta->'{field_name}'"

    # Prepare the value as a Python list, and wrap it with Jsonb
    jsonb_value = Jsonb(value)

    return f"{field} @> %s", jsonb_value

COMPARISON_OPERATORS = {
    ...
    "contains": _contains,
}

